# git rebase "already up to date" when I know I am behind

Tags: git, bitbucket

```
git switch develop
git checkout -b <branchName>
(do work here)
npm run lint/prettier/test
git stash
git rebase develop
git stash pop
git commit -a -m ''
git push origin <branchName>
```

I'm having this issue when I'm working on my branch and the next day I try to rebase before I commit "Current branch  is up to date." and when I commit bitbucket says I'm like x commits behind sync now.

Why an I having these issues every time and what can I do to fix this? This is my git command flow.

The git rebase never works and always says I'm up to date. The solution I've been doing is just cloning the repo every single time and copy pasting my changes before commit/pushing. Halp me!

Comment: You aren't fetching `develop` from the remote

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
git rebase develop
```

then develop refers to your local develop branch.
If develop has been changed on the remote repo you should first integrate those changes into your develop. I.e.

```
git switch develop
git pull
git switch <branchName>
git rebase develop
```

Or alternatively a little faster without updating local develop first

```
# stay on <branchName>
git fetch
git rebase origin/develop
```